# How to redirect a URL containing smartquotes via .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is there a way to redirect a URL containing smart quotes via .htaccess? I'm using the following rules. Only the last one seems to work:

```
RewriteRule ^8-%E2%80%9Crules%E2%80%9D-for-social-advertising$ /8-rules-for-social-advertising [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^8-“rules”-for-social-advertising$ /8-rules-for-social-advertising [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^8-%25E2%2580%259Crules%25E2%2580%259D-for-social-advertising$ /8-rules-for-social-advertising [R=301,L]
```

When I surf to [http://blog.eloqua.com/8-“rules”-for-social-advertising/](http://blog.eloqua.com/8-%E2%80%9Crules%E2%80%9D-for-social-advertising/) or http://blog.eloqua.com/8-%E2%80%9Crules%E2%80%9D-for-social-advertising it doesn't get redirected.

But if I go to http://blog.eloqua.com/8-%25E2%2580%259Crules%25E2%2580%259D-for-social-advertising everything works just fine.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, it's slipping passed the rules you have provided.

The reason is because the unicode characters represented by the %E2%80%9C and %E2%80%9D (aka microsoft smartquotes) have already been turned into their unicode representation within Apache. As such you need to properly match the bytestream representing those characters within apache.

In order to properly redirect urls such as this:

```
http://www.example.com/8-%E2%80%9Crules%E2%80%9D-for-social-advertising
```

You would use a rule like this:

```
http://www.example.com/8-\xE2\x80\x9Crules\xE2\x80\x9D-for-social-advertising
```